# PuPHPet - PHP Error after editing file

Tags: php, vagrant, puphpet

A few days ago my `PuPHPet-Box` started throwing PHP-Errors *after editing a file* and refreshing the browser. Seems like the file get's locked after editing & saving:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/var/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/xxx/public/views/filters.php):
>   failed to open stream: Input/output error in
>   /var/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/xxx/admin/class-xxx.php on line 1309
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/var/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/xxx/public/views/filters.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/xxx/admin/class-xxx.php on line 1309

After refreshing the browser multiple times (about 3-5 times), the error is gone.

The file exists, it just has been changed. Also it's not matter what file is changed, the error comes back.

Here is the line referenced in the warning:

```
/**
* Renders the view that displays the filters
*
* @since    0.1.0
*/
public function recipe_filters() {
   include_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/xxx/public/views/filters.php';
}
```

I'm using `PhpStorm (2017.3.3)`, `PuPHPet` and `WordPress (4.9.3)` on `OSX (10.13.3)`.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: May you should read the error message and look at `class-xxx.php on line 1309`

Comment: Like I stated in my question, the files are existing. I'm editing my question to state this clearly.

Comment: Where do I say they don't exist? I just told you to look up the line 1309 from the mentioned file. Would I suggest you do that when the files don't exist? No. So read caruflly what people are saying to you. I just want you to have a look at the file, not more and not less.

Comment: No offense, there is no error in the code. It's enough to move a line or adding a blank line to get this error.

Comment: So I looked at this line, I can't see an error. Still no solution, error appears randomly, depending on what file was edited.

Comment: We can't help you without any code.

Comment: What code should I post? Still no solution. I generated a new PuPHPet machine, still the same.

Comment: It`s definitively a PuPHPet issue. I switched to MAMP, at least for this project. Everythings working as expected.